# Custom javascript not working

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs

I'm trying to inject a scroll to anchor javascript globally in Magento 2.

More specifically this script:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
    var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
    if( target.length ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

I have taken the reference from [this blog post](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin-2).

I converted it to include defines and stuff:

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "jquery/ui"
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
    var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
    if( target.length ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
});

});
```

And injecting it in to my themes `default_head_blocks.xml` with `<link src="js/custom.js" />`

The injection works but I am getting the following error in Chrome console:

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function ($) {
    'use strict';

require.js:166
```

Comment: Check this answer, it might match your situation https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/255077/76597

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `defined` use `require` Like this:

```
require([
    'jquery',
    "jquery/ui"
], function($){
    'use strict';

    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
        var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
        if( target.length ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't know if it's the best way, but it worked and I didn't have to touch the header file.

Comment: Yes, it is the way of Magento to write js anywhere in your code. using define includes the files that you add in it

Answer (score 5):

Add an external JS in the following way :

Try this,

Add your custom js in the following path.

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme-name/web/js/nameofjs.js

then you need to add **requirejs-config.js** to the following path.

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme-name/requirejs-config.js

then add the following code in it

```
 var config = {
    paths: {            
            'your_js_name' : 'js/nameofjs', 
        },                                                                
    shim: {
    'your_js_name': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
  }
};
```

and add the below code to load custom **js**, In your case it would be **header.phtml** in **Magento_Theme** folder in your theme

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme-name/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml

```
<script>
require(['jquery','your_js_name'],function($) {
$(window).load(function () {
     /*alert('load from external jquery');*/
});});
</script>
```

Hope this helps and this is correct way to load any custom js in M2 as far as I know.

Peace :)

Comment: Nice one Prathap, you elaborate well, how to add js. +1

Comment: Do the above things and it will add js when the script loaded

Comment: See this get more about how js is loading in magento 2
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/264679/magento-2-use-of-shims-in-requirejs-config-js-file/264685#264685

Comment: I have to override the header.phtml template? Where in that file does the code go?

Comment: Your header.phtml must be in this path app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme-name/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml

Comment: You'll find it in your theme files. @John

Comment: I don't have one. It is a child theme of Luma.

Comment: Then you can add it in custom module as well

Answer (score 2):

In Maggento 2 the concept of requirejs is restricting you to add the an external js which is not bound into any module. So what you can do is simply create a custom module [follow this](https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/) & define your js there into that module at below location

> Magento_root/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/file.js

It should contains the code as follows

```
require([
    'jquery',
    "jquery/ui"
], function($){
    'use strict';

    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
        var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
        if( target.length ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

Define it into your requirejs-config.js located at below location

> Magento_root/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

It should Contains the code as follows:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            module_js_denotation_name: 'Vendor_module/js/file',
        }
    }
};
```

Now you can call it into any phtml file you want to load it as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'module_js_denotation_name'], function($, myscript) {
        myscript();
    });
</script>
```

For your requirement you need to call it into the `header.phtml` or the `footer.phtml` file.

You can also create your own phtml file at `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/template/template.phtml` & call it there & with the help of layout `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xaml` file you can inject your template file to the theme (I am supposing that you no how to inject your phtml to your theme through the layout files).

> Note: Make sure after doing this you are running the below commands o
>   register your module & deploy the contents & make sure you are not making any changes to the default magento file always make the changes to your custome code that is inside the `Magento_root/app` directory
>
> ```
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
> php bin/magento cache:flush
> ```