# TypeError: require is not a function

Tags: magento2, javascript

I add JS file in custom module

`Vendor\Module\view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <head>
     <css src="Vendor_Module::css/test.css"/>
     <script src="Vendor_Module::js/test.js"/>
   </head>
</page>
```

Add  js file in web folder as below path:

`view/adminhtml/web/js/test.js`

code for checking   .

```
require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
    $(document).ready(function($) {
        console.log('asdf');
    });
});
```

File include in admin panel But error is `TypeError: require is not a function`
how can see message in console ?

Comment: don't you mean `define` instead of `require`? also is this the javascript code that is in you JS-file or is this somewhere else?

Comment: use also define but same error `TypeError: define is not a defined`

Comment: "define is not a defined" is not a message javascript would EVER print. please make sure that you provide us the correct error

Comment: It seems like you are overwriting the `default.xml` in module backend and therefore require.js is not loaded anymore

Comment: Refer [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/264940/custom-javascript-not-working/264946#264946) may be it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to add js in module, the best way is to add it via **require-js**

> 1. app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            prince: 'Vendor_module/js/prince',
        }
    }
};
```

> 2. app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/prince.js

```
define(['jquery'], function($){
   "use strict";
       alert("Yesss, it works !");
});
```

> 3. app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/file.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'prince'], function($, prince) {
    });
</script>
```

**Don't forget to :**

- `clean the cache`
- `clean var/view_preprocessed content`
- `clean pub/static content`
- `deploy the static content : php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`