# Lazy load Js not working in Magento2.3.1 Version

Tags: magento2, lazyload

We use Magento2.3.1, in product list page showing error like

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).lazyload is not a function.

While using Porto theme of Magento 2.x.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/264940/custom-javascript-not-working/264941#264941

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran, This function already working in Magento2.3.0 but 2.3.1 not working.

Comment: Not sure about it, but with above information I could only sense there much be dependency issue

Comment: can you share the code where you called `$(SOMETHING).lazyload`

Comment: Once include lazyload function then automaticallyy its working.


define([
    'jquery',
    'Mageplaza_AjaxLayer/js/action/submit-filter',
    'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils',
    'jquery/ui',
    'accordion',
    'js/jquery.lazyload',
    'productListToolbarForm'
], function ($, submitFilterAction, ultil) {
    "use strict";
});

Answer (score 2):

To complete this Answer. Soundararajan m is correct but he doesn't specify which files to update. They're located at

`app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Mageplaza_AjaxLayer/web/js/view/layer.js` 
  `app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation/web/js/view/layer.js`

Update the top of the layer.js file to this

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Mageplaza_AjaxLayer/js/action/submit-filter',
    'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils',
    'jquery/ui',
    'accordion',
    'js/jquery.lazyload',
    'productListToolbarForm'
], function ($, submitFilterAction, ultil) {
...
```

This will solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

I got solution for this question after refer my code.

Once include lazyload function then automaticallyy its working. 
File Location:

```
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Mageplaza_AjaxLayer/web/js/view/layer.js
```

```
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation/web/js/view/layer.js
```

```
define([ 'jquery', 'Mageplaza_AjaxLayer/js/action/submit-filter', 'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils', 'jquery/ui', 'accordion', 'js/jquery.lazyload', 'productListToolbarForm' ], function ($, submitFilterAction, ultil) { "use strict"; });
```

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue using weltpixel theme lazyload extension. Can anyone tell where to include the above line to resolve the issue.

Comment: @chanchal Sorry no one answered this for you. There's two files where this is missing. app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Mageplaza_AjaxLayer/web/js/view/layer.js
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation/web/js/view/layer.js

Answer (score 0):

In you extension add below js:

> view/frontend/web/js/jquery.lazyload.js
>
> view/frontend/web/js/lazyload.js

now configure requirejs:

> view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            LazyLoad: 'Vendor_Module/js/lazyload'
        }
    }
};
```

Add below code in phtml file

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "LazyLoad": {}
    }
}
</script>
```

> You can try this extension as well:
>   https://www.weltpixel.com/magento-2-lazy-load-product-extension.html