# Magento 2.3.0 add custom JS in theme, using require js

Tags: javascript, custom, magento2.3, requirejs-config.js

I want to add a custom js - pricing.js in my theme folder using require js

I call the script in defaultheadBlock.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300" src_type="url" />
        <css src="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:300,400,500|Covered+By+Your+Grace" src_type="url" />
        <css src="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <css src="css/slick.min.css" />
        <css src="css/magnific-popup.css" />
        <css src="font/icont-fonts.min.css" />
        <css src="css/style.css" />
        <css src="css/animate.css" />
        <css src="css/labs.css" />
        <css src="css/masonry.css" />
        <css src="css/custom.css" />
        <script src="js/pricing.js" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Also added the code in require-config.js

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        "bootstrapminify":  'Magento_Theme/js/bootstrap.min',
        "slick": 'Magento_Theme/js/slick.min',
        "tonyMenu":'Magento_Theme/js/tonyMenu',
        "sliders": 'Magento_Theme/js/sliders',
        jquery_bridget: 'Magento_Theme/js/jquery-bridget',
        "isotope": 'Magento_Theme/js//isotope.pkgd.min',
        countdown_pl: 'Magento_Theme/js/countdown/jquery.plugin.min',
        countdown_cd: 'Magento_Theme/js/countdown/jquery.countdown.min',
        "calculator_home": 'Magento_Theme/js/pricing'
    },
    "shim": {
        "bootstrapminify": { deps :['jquery'] },
        "slick" : { deps :['jquery'] },
        "tonyMenu" : { deps :['jquery', 'slick'] },
        "sliders" : { deps :['jquery', 'slick'] },
        jquery_bridget : { deps :['jquery'] },
        isotope : { deps :['jquery', 'jquery_bridget'] },
        countdown_pl : { deps :['jquery'] },
        countdown_cd : { deps :['jquery', 'countdown_pl'] },
        "calculator_home": { deps :['jquery','bootstrapminify'] }
    },
    deps: [
        'Magento_Theme/js/theme'
    ]
};
```

but after chcking the code I found the script is being called but on clcking the pub/static/ url is not found  error.

[enter link description here](http://%3Cscript%20%20type=%22text/javascript%22%20%20src=%22http://confidentialcouture.co.in/ANGEL/pub/static/version1554120415/frontend/Etheme/shopy/en_US/js/pricing.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E)

Comment: Try this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/264940/custom-javascript-not-working/264941#264941

Answer (score 1):

Please try below steps.

create file custom.js

```
require([
    'jquery',
    "jquery/ui"
], function($){
    'use strict';

    $('a').on('click', function(event) {
       console.log(1);
    });
});
```

Define it into your requirejs-config.js located at below location

```
Magento_root/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/requirejs-config.js
```

It should contain the code as follows:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            module_js_denotation_name: 'js/file',
        }
    }
};
```

Now, you can call into any phtml file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'module_js_denotation_name'], function($, myscript) {
        myscript();
    });
</script>
```

After that run below commands and clear cache,

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Thanks